# MVPMosby and Mockito

Tags: android, android-studio, mockito, mvp

I'm struggling to make unit tests using `Mockito` and `MVPMosby`. I'm attaching the presenter to the view, but in my `init()` method, `presenter.getView()` is returning null. Here's my code:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MainActivityUnitTest {

    @Mock
    public MainView mainView;
    @Mock
    public MainPresenter mainPresenter;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mainPresenter.attachView(mainView);
    }

    @Test
    public void asd() throws Exception {
        mainPresenter.init(null);
        verify(mainView).setRefreshing(true);
    }
}
```

Am I doing somethig wrong here? What's the proper way of unit testing with `MVPMosby` and `Mockito`?

Comment: Which class are you trying to test. You should not mock the class that you are trying to test. If you are testing the presenter, create an instance of the presenter and you can mock the view to verify view interactions

Comment: Can i also mock the context, cause my presenter's constructor has a context parameter, but when i'm doing that the context in my presenter is null.

Comment: if `init` does not use context or does not relay on any result of calling method of `context` object  then yes, you can mock it. Be aware that methods of mocked objects do nothing and return nulls or false until you dont specify it by yourself.

Comment: @DrilonBlakqori Sorry for the delayed response. Yes, the android test framework provides [MockContext](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/mock/MockContext.html). You need to create instrumentation test. You can find the details in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html)